# What happens to messages with no matching Listener in Spring-Kafka?

Tags: spring-kafka

My understanding of the @KafkaListener is that messages are consumed by matching the listener method's argument type with the message type.

What happens to messages that do not have a matching listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean. What leads you to believe that?

`@KafkaListener` on a `Method` means there is a consumer (listener container) for each method so all methods get all records (unless they are in the same consumer group or you assign partitions manually).

`@KafkaListener` on a `Class` means you have to annotate multiple methods with `@KafkaHandler` and the framework will find which handler method to invoke based on the deserialized payload; the value deserializer must be able to deserialize the expected multiple types.

You can designate exactly one `@KafkaHandler` as the `default` handler (which is invoked if there is no match) - usually with an `Object` parameter.

If there is no match and no default handler method, the record goes to the configured `ErrorHandler`.

The default error handler logs the failure, but you can add your own to do whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Actually what I was seeing was the consumer starting after the message had been sent in a test, and could find no reason for that despite stepping through. Starting at the earliest offset fixed the issue. Appreciate your answer anyway, it adds clarity.

Comment: Yes, it's a common mistake, especially in tests; whenever I write a listener, I always go to the properties first and set it to `earliest` (and `enable.auto.commit=false` - which is the new default in the upcoming 2.3 release - where we override kafka's default of true; I prefer to use the container to commit the offsets more reliably than the client).